# How to revert to stock ROM on HTC One M7

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, stock-android, rom, htc

My HTC One M7 phone is S-OFF, has the latest firmware 7.19.401.2, and has nicely installed "ViperOne+9.0.0-fix", the recovery is TWRP 2.8.6.0. Everything works very well, except that the proximity sensor seems erratic, and when I have a call the ear seems to press different programs on the touchscreen. I would like to return to complete HTC stock ROM so that I assure myself the proximity sensor works well enough (or does not).

Do I have to downgrade the firmware to be able to install the stock ROM?

I have downloaded the stock ROM `PN07IMG_M7_UL_L50_SENSE60_MR_HTC_Europe_7.19.401.2_Radio_4T.35.3218.16_10.33Q.1718.01L_release_421790_signed.zip` but seem to be unable to install from TWRP.

Or maybe the only way is via fastboot? With the commands:

1. `htc_fastboot oem rebootRUU`
2. `htc_fastboot flash zip RUU.zip`
3. `htc_fastboot reboot-bootloader`

Can someone more experienced give some advice, please?

Comment: An officially signed ruu.zip needs to be flashed through htc fastboot because it is encrypted.

Comment: @Bo Lawson. I did it that way, so far looks good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have One M8 but I think the process should be about the same. You'll want to find the right RUU for your model. I'm not certain which model/carrier you have, so here is an overview list: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2428276.

To relock your bootloader (necessary for RUU), make sure you have ADB installed, connect your phone to your PC. Then type the following commands:

```
adb devices
adb shell
su
echo -ne ‘\x00\x00\x00\x00’ | dd of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p2 bs=1 seek=33796
exit
exit
adb reboot bootloader
```

When that is done, simply run the RUU exe that you downloaded from the first link. If you found the right one, it should restore your phone completely to stock.